# Firebase SDK crashes on FBLPromise with unrecognized selector

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-authentication, cocoapods, google-authentication

I've followed the [Firebase docs for integrating my iOS app with Google Sign-in authentication](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/google-signin?authuser=0#objective-c), and now that I have the "sign-in with google" button showing up it crashes immediately with this `[FBLPromise HTTPBody]: unrecognized selector sent to instance`. I've found other threads where people had the same issue [[1](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/google-signin?authuser=0#objective-c), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67602772/app-is-keep-on-crashing-fblpromise-httpbody-unrecognized-selector-sent-to-inst)] but there isn't a lot of useful information out there. Some people believe it has to do with the Podfile, below I'm attaching the crash dump as well as my Podfile content. Thanks in advance for any help!

Podfile

```
# platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'ApartaFitPlayground' do
  # Comment the next line if you don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for ApartaFitPlayground
  pod 'MaterialComponents'
  pod 'FirebaseUI'
end
```

Crash dump

```
2022-02-21 17:42:41.609421-0800 ApartaFitPlayground[10860:1538705] -[FBLPromise HTTPBody]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x60000207bb40
2022-02-21 17:42:41.611388-0800 ApartaFitPlayground[10860:1538705] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[FBLPromise HTTPBody]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x60000207bb40'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001803e1188 __exceptionPreprocess + 236
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0000000180193384 objc_exception_throw + 56
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001803f0530 +[NSObject(NSObject) instanceMethodSignatureForSelector:] + 0
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001803e53fc ___forwarding___ + 1408
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001803e743c _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 92
    5   GoogleDataTransport                 0x000000010578dc5c -[GDTCCTUploadOperation updateNextUploadTimeWithResponse:forTarget:] + 76
    6   GoogleDataTransport                 0x000000010578d14c __64-[GDTCCTUploadOperation sendURLRequestWithBatch:target:storage:]_block_invoke + 64
    7   FBLPromises                         0x0000000104fc92c0 __56-[FBLPromise chainOnQueue:chainedFulfill:chainedReject:]_block_invoke.67 + 80
    8   FBLPromises                         0x0000000104fc89d4 __44-[FBLPromise observeOnQueue:fulfill:reject:]_block_invoke_2 + 88
    9   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001061a3e94 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 24
    10  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001061a5694 _dispatch_client_callout + 16
    11  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001061aca88 _dispatch_lane_serial_drain + 1300
    12  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001061ad534 _dispatch_lane_invoke + 436
    13  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001061b9664 _dispatch_workloop_worker_thread + 820
    14  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00000001c99caad4 _pthread_wqthread + 284
    15  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00000001c99c988c start_wqthread + 8
)
libc++abi: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
dyld4 config: DYLD_ROOT_PATH=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/Users/luisdelgado/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ApartaFitPlayground-eamkhaawlsqbqnclyjwxadvzaxpd/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/usr/lib/system/introspection DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/usr/lib/libBacktraceRecording.dylib:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/usr/lib/libMainThreadChecker.dylib:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/Developer/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DTDDISupport.framework/libViewDebuggerSupport.dylib DYLD_FRAMEWORK_PATH=/Users/luisdelgado/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ApartaFitPlayground-eamkhaawlsqbqnclyjwxadvzaxpd/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator:/Users/luisdelgado/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ApartaFitPlayground-eamkhaawlsqbqnclyjwxadvzaxpd/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/PackageFrameworks
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[FBLPromise HTTPBody]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x60000207bb40'
terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
CoreSimulator 783.5 - Device: iPhone 12 Pro Max (EAEF114F-D624-40EB-831C-40ADDD5966D9) - Runtime: iOS 15.2 (19C51) - DeviceType: iPhone 12 Pro Max
```

Answer (score 4):

In my experience, this error usually happens because you have multiple static libs/frameworks/sdks that use Firebase, and the firebase implementation for that function is different between them. In your case it seems the FBLPromise class that the linker chose to include doesn't have the httpBody function.

If you don't include the "-ObjC" flag, by default, Xcode will just pick the first firebase classes that it finds and link them in the final binary.
If you do use the "-ObjC" flag or you use "force_load("path/to/MyFramework.framework") , you'll probably have linking errors that say it found a symbol in multiples paths and doesn't know which one to include.

There's multiple solutions for this issue: you can make all your dependencies use the same firebase version, you can put the firebase classes in a namespace, etc.

My recommendation would be to use the "-ObjC" flag, get the link error about duplicated symbols and see where all those firebase classes are coming from. After that, you can communite with those SDKs and tell them to namespace / rename the symbols to avoid conflicts.
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Add `platform :ios, '10.0'` and run `pod update`.

Recent versions of Firebase require at least iOS 10. If there are still problems, see the suggestions at https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/issues/7939

Answer (score 0):

Find your `.debug` file then find `OTHER_LDFLAGS` and comment out all of the framework files, that worked for me:

```
OTHER_LDFLAGS = $(inherited) -ObjC -l"c++" -l"icucore" -l"sqlite3" -l"z" -framework "CFNetwork" -framework "CoreTelephony" //-framework "FBLPromises" -framework "FirebaseAnalytics" -framework "FirebaseAuth" -framework "FirebaseCore" -framework "FirebaseCoreDiagnostics" -framework "FirebaseDatabase" -framework "FirebaseInstallations" -framework "Foundation" -framework "GTMSessionFetcher" -framework "GoogleAppMeasurement" -framework "GoogleAppMeasurementIdentitySupport" -framework "GoogleDataTransport" -framework "GoogleUtilities" -framework "SafariServices" -framework "Security" -framework "StoreKit" -framework "SystemConfiguration" -framework "UIKit" -framework "leveldb" -framework "nanopb"
```

Comment: Just trying to help didn’t have to dislike my answer 

Comment: thank to your advice now i have to add everything manually back because project is not compiling after removing